# How to launch Page only once when app is opened for first time?

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

I have a WelcomePage.xaml, which I want to be started only once when the app is started for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do it is in OnLaunched, I check for a saved value that will let me know if it has been launched before.  I then navigate to the right page based on that.

```
 if (!ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Keys.Contains("Launched"))
 {
     rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(WelcomePage));
 }
 else
 {
     rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
 }
```

On the WelcomePage, you would save the value.

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Add("Launched", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Store a value to [LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings).

Eg:

```
var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
var localSettings = applicationData.localSettings;
localSettings.values["IsFirstLaunch"] = true;
```

You can read more about its basic usage in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).